# Creating a new folder template in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I am unable to sort my files the way I want because Windows Explorer offers only 5 folder templates: General Items, Documents, Pictures, Videos and Music.

I need another template in order to sort the files inside >1000 folders.

Is it possible to create a sixth folder template? And if so, how?

The templates can be found here: Windows Explorer -> View -> Customize this folder -> Customize tab.

[image]